# Customizing TestResults display in TestNG

Tags: java, testng

I like to customize and display more information for Test suites or tests like Test Run times, for eg: adding more information to below displayed output

```
===============================================
Demo-Suite
Total tests run: 19, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Any suggestions how to add more to above info like adding Average Test Suite run time etc.,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution for you:

1. Let us assume we have a TestNG script with 3 Testcases, where 1 Testcase passes & 2 Testcases fails.

   ```
   @Test
   public void test1()
   {
       Assert.assertEquals(12, 13);
   }

   @Test
   public void test2()
   {
       System.out.println("Testcase 2 Started");
       Assert.assertEquals(12, 13, "Dropdown count doesnot match");
       System.out.println("Testcase 2 Completed");
   }

   @Test
   public void test3()
   {
       System.out.println("Testcase 3 Started");
       Assert.assertEquals("Hello", "Hello", "Words doesnot match. Please raise a Bug.");
       System.out.println("Testcase 3 Completed");
   }
   ```

So you get the result on the console as: `Tests run: 3, Failures: 2, Skips: 0`

2. Now to look at the granular details you can do the following:

   a. Move to the tab "Results of running class your_class_name". Here you will observe some more fine prints of the execution in-terms of Default Suite Execution Time, Default Test Execution Time, Time taken for each Individual Test, etc.

[image: TestCase Execution timer]

```
 b. Now to view more details you can click on the "Open TestNG report" icon located on the top bar of "Results of running class your_class_name". This will provide you a lot more information about Testcase Results & Time taken.
```

[image: Granular Information]

2. Now if you need more detailed information in the form of Dashboard, Execution Info & System Details, you can integrate "ExtentReports" within TestNG to get some superb graphical representations of your test execution.

Dashboard:

[image: Dashboard]

Execution Info:

[image: Execution Info]

System Details:

[image]

Let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks @Dev, but what im trying to do is customize the results info in the console itself

Comment: @SruVar Your question was on "display more information for Test suites or tests like Test Run times". If my Answer have catered to your Question can you Accept the answer as a Solution and Publish a new Question with your updated queries? Thanks.

Comment: integrating ExtentReports definetly helps. But with current version of Extent Reports i see different page layout from the above screenshots. But i will publish a new question on that.

Comment: @SruVar great decision. Go ahead. Try it out. If you are stuck, post your query.I will be glad to help you out. Don't forget to voteup these useful answers. Thanks.

Comment: @SruVar You wanted to change what the console reports. My answer pointed you exactly to the relevant part of the documentation and the someone's example project on the web. So why this is the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

> Too long by 3 characters

to be a comment.

[`TestNG` documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#logging) is your friend. You could provide your own implementation. Very basic example [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/testng/testng_custom_reporter.htm).

Another approach is to use `HTML/XML Report generation` and to inspect the data from a test run there. It's a bunch of `html` pages with pretty colors and some data. Sample report [here](http://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/testng-reports/). Also if your project is using `Apache Maven` than just enable the `surefire plug-in`. [Sample report here](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/surefire-report.html).